# removing duplicates from the column of a dataframe pandas

Tags: python, pandas

```
ID       Info
1       '123','34','123'
2       'NA' ,'12','NA','567'
```

To remove the duplicates from the Info column,I am using the following code.It's giving me df['Info'] series sans duplicates

```
df['Info'].str.split(',').map(set).agg(','.join)
```

How do I get the following dataframe?I need to get back the data frame that contains 'ID' and 'Info' column(sans duplicates)

```
ID       Info
1       '123','34'
2       'NA' ,'12','567'
```

Comment: Use `df['Info'].str.split(',').map(set).agg(','.join).reset_index(name='Info')`

Comment: I am not able to get the 'ID' column that way.I need to get the original data frame that contains 'ID' and 'Info' column(sans duplicates)

Comment: You are right, need `df = df.set_index('ID')['Info'].str.split(',').map(set).agg(','.join).reset_index(name='Info')`

Comment: It worked.Thanks for your help